# Looking for a Domain Manager

Tags: domains, management

I am looking for the best Domain "management" company. Have about 500+ domains at the moment and acquire more on a daily basis.  Would prefer to have a full-service company take over the daily management and selling side of all domains and want to list them on afternic, godaddy, etc. and host them all through Moniker.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A domain park company? or DNS management such as A Records...

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are an individual and not representing a corporate portfolio of branded domain names, right? If you are that, then there are services like MarkMonitor that could help you, but will cost major money.

If you are an individual, then you are similar to me. I have looked into this some myself and I am not aware of any company that will actually manage a portfolio in the ways you mention.

I'd suggest to look at Protrada - I've never used them, but lots of domainers do and apparently one thing they support is a multiple listing feature for selling. http://www.protrada.com/. Not sure about 'daily management' support - I'm not really sure what that means.

Another company to consider might be Domain Name Sales. http://domainnamesales.com/. These guys will screen your portfolio to see if it meets their quality standards.